# Error al añadir modulos en python

Tags: python

he borrado python he hecho de todo pero no consigo hacer que las librerías que he instalado funcionen:

Lo añado desde pycharm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Desde setting igual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y desde la consola con el pip tampoco me lo detecta alguno puediera ayudarme en esto?, es bastante frustante porque ya ni hablar de conseguir hacer código si ni siquiera puedo importar estas librerías agradecería bastante la ayuda para resolver esto

Variables de entorno de mi sistema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De donde ejecuta el interprete:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hago un up para ver si alguien puede ayudar